# Determining the sign of an equation given constraints

Tags: inequality

I'm given $-\frac{1}{2}(a+1)^2+\frac{1}{2}(a+1)\sqrt{(a+1)^2-4(a+b)}+2(a+b)$ and need to determine its sign, under the constraint that $(a+1)^2>4(a+b)$.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this. So far, I know that $-\frac{1}{2}(a+1)^2 + 2(a+b) < 0$ by the constraint equation, but I can't figure out how to go from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $ (a+1)^2 - 4(a+b) = k > 0$.

We want to determine the signage of
$$ -\frac{k}{2} + \frac{1}{2} (a+1) \sqrt{k} = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{k} ( a+1 - \sqrt{k}). $$

Note that $ (a+1) > \sqrt{k} $ iff $ 4 (a+b) > 0$.

It is possible for

- $ a+b > 0$, $(a+1)^2 > 4(a+b)$ EG $ a = 1, b = 0 $.
- $a + b < 0$, $(a+1)^2 > 4(a+b)$ EG $ a = 0, b = -1 $.

Hence, the sign is indeterminate.

Note: If we are restricted to positive / non-negative terms, then we can conclude that $ a + b > 0$, so the term is positive.